# Normal pointer vs Auto pointer (std::auto_ptr)

Tags: c++, pointers, auto-ptr

Code snippet (normal pointer)

```
int *pi = new int;
int i = 90;
pi = &i;
int k = *pi + 10;
cout<<k<<endl; 
delete pi;

[Output: 100]
```

Code snippet (auto pointer)

Case 1:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pi(new int);
int i = 90;
pi = &i;
int k = *pi + 10; //Throws unhandled exception error at this point while debugging.
cout<<k<<endl;
//delete pi; (It deletes by itself when goes out of scope. So explicit 'delete' call not required)
```

Case 2:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pi(new int);
int i = 90;
*pi = 90;
int k = *pi + 10;
cout<<k<<endl;

[Output: 100]
```

Can someone please tell why it failed to work for case 1?

Comment: Case 1 should actually fail to compile (no operator to do `pi = &i;`), so I can't see how you can be debugging this code.

Comment: It didn't fail to compile. (I'm compiling with vc8)

Comment: You seem to have come across this bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98871/ - Ok, @visitor already found that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to bind `auto_pt`r to a stack allocated variable.

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pi(new int);
int i = 90;
pi = &i;
```

never try to do that - only bind `auto_ptr` to variables allocated with `new`. Otherwise auto_ptr will try to `delete` a stack allocated variable and that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok. I changed as below, it worked. 

{ 
int *i = new int; 
*i = 90; 
pi = &i; 
}

One interesting point. The moment I copied 'i' to 'pi', then 'i' became NULL. (I think that is how auto_ptr designed to work)

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 *fails to compile*, because you simply can't assign a plain pointer to an `auto_ptr`. If you want to change the pointer that the `auto_ptr` is looking after, you can use the reset method:

```
pi.reset(&i);
```

Now `pi` will delete the pointer it was storing earlier.

However, here you'd be storing the address of a stack allocated variable which *must not be deleted*. The purpose of `std::auto_ptr` is to manage a dynamically allocated variable.

---

What you are observing with VC++ 2005 appears to be a bug in the implementation of a feature (ability to assign pointers to `std::auto_ptr`) which is apparently unspecified in the standard (whether it should or shouldn't compile).

In the next standard `std::auto_ptr` will be deprecated anyway, so you might rather experiment with saner smart pointers (`boost::scoped_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Thanks for your view.

When I assigned like pi = &i, during debugging, while dereferencing (*), it raised an exception. When I assigned like pi.reset(&i), it succeeded while dereferencing , but when the program came out of scope, it crashed. I can understand this because, auto_ptr has tried to delete the stack allocated memory when method goes out of scope.

Comment: It appears you have stumbled upon a bug in the library implementation: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98871/memory-corruption-in-auto-ptr-operator-auto-ptr-ref. Just remember that assigning a pointer to `auto_ptr` is not portable (I would have thought it was the intention of the standard that this shouldn't compile, but perhaps it is unspecified).